# Matching content between 2 CSVs and write the values

Tags: powershell

Each user has a domain1.com and domain2.com separate email address. I would like to compare email addresses within CSV1 & CSV2 and if the prefix name on their emails match, pull the value into CSV1.  This will later allow me to run other powershell commands on a source / target kind of scenario.

I have it somewhat, working below although the domain2_email column isn't matching the user row. It looks to be trying to import all of them into an array.

I have used Joe.Bloggs here to test if the IF is working, but ideally - I would like to have it search each entry in CSV1.

**End Goal:**

- Search CSV2 with the name part of the primarySMTPAddress value and if match, put them into another column within CSV1.
- CSV1 will have a user with domain1.com and domain2.com values within the row.

```
# Pull in mailbox data
Get-EXOMailbox  -Filter {EmailAddresses -like *@domain1.com -and RecipientTypeDetails -notlike "SharedMailbox"} |  Export-Csv -Path './domain1export.csv'
Get-EXOMailbox  -Filter {EmailAddresses -like *@domain2.com -and RecipientTypeDetails -notlike "SharedMailbox"} |  Export-Csv -Path './domain2xexport.csv'
 
$outfile = './outfile.csv'
$finalOutfile = './finalOutfile.csv'
 
# Check if outfile.csv exists, if it does - delete.
if (test-path $outfile) {
    Remove-Item $outfile
    Write-Host "$outfile has been deleted"
}
 
$CSV1 = Import-Csv -Path './domain1export.csv'
$CSV2 = Import-Csv -Path './domain2export.csv'
 
$CVS1 | foreach {
    # Splits the name prefix from email
    $_ | Select-Object *,@{Name='Name_Prefix';Expression={$_.PrimarySmtpAddress.Split("@")[0] }} | Export-Csv -Path $outfile -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
 
$outfile2 = Import-Csv -Path $outfile
foreach ($item in $outfile2) {
    if ($outfile2.Name_Prefix -match "Joe.Bloggs") {
        $item | Select-Object *,@{Name='Domain2_email';Expression={$CSV2.PrimarySmtpAddress}} | Export-Csv -Path $finalOutfile -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

**Data**

CSV1

```
UserPrincipalName,Alias,DisplayName,EmailAddresses,PrimarySmtpAddress,RecipientType,RecipientTypeDetails
joe.bloggs@domain1.com,d1bloggsj,Domain1 Joe Bloggs,SIP:joe.blogggs@domain1.com SMTP:joe.blogggs@domain1.com,Joe.Bloggs@domain1.com,UserMailbox,UserMailbox
foo.bar@domain1.com,d1barf,Domain1 Foo Bar,SIP:foo.bar@domain1.com SMTP:foo.bar@domain1.com  ,foo.bar@domain1.com,UserMailbox,UserMailbox
```

CSV2

```
UserPrincipalName,Alias,DisplayName,EmailAddresses,PrimarySmtpAddress,RecipientType,RecipientTypeDetails
joe.bloggs@domain2.com,d2bloggsj,Domain2 Joe Bloggs,SIP:joe.blogggs@domain2.com SMTP:joe.blogggs@domain2.com,Joe.Bloggs@domain2.com,UserMailbox,UserMailbox
foo.bar@domain2.com,d1barf,Domain2 Foo Bar,SIP:foo.bar@domain2.com SMTP:foo.bar@domain2.com  ,foo.bar@domain2.com,UserMailbox,UserMailbox
```

Comment: Could you provide data samples (as plain text) of what you have and what you want? Easier to help you that way

Comment: Hi, i have added some CSV data.  Essentially, the only thing different in the CSVs will be the domain and display names.  Does this help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So both CSV1 and CSV2 would contain a column called `PrimarySmtpAddress` and you need to match those, correct?

Try

```
$CSV1 = Import-Csv -Path './domain1export.csv'
$CSV2 = Import-Csv -Path './domain2export.csv'

$result = foreach ($item in $csv1) {
    $prefix = $item.PrimarySmtpAddress.Split("@")[0]
    # try and find a match
    $matching = $csv2 | Where-Object { $_.PrimarySmtpAddress.Split("@")[0] -eq $prefix }
    $item | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Name_Prefix'; Expression = {$prefix }},
                             @{Name = 'Domain2_email';Expression = {$matching.PrimarySmtpAddress }} 
}

$finalOutfile = './finalOutfile.csv'
$result | Export-Csv -Path $finalOutfile -NoTypeInformation
```

BTW. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-exomailbox?view=exchange-ps#parameters), the `-Filter` parameter is a string, not a scriptblock, so you should use

```
Get-EXOMailbox  -Filter "EmailAddresses -like '*@domain1.com' -and RecipientTypeDetails -ne 'SharedMailbox'"
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you.  I just need it to list the fields that come up with no match in the Domain2_email column and i'm pretty much there.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, first create a hash table using the Csv1 where the **Keys** are the mail prefix and the **Values** are the mail suffix and the, using a calculated property with `Select-Object` you can search for each line on Csv2 if the mail's prefix exists and obtain the corresponding *Values* (mail suffix):

**Note**, below code assumes that there are unique mail prefixes, if this was not the case, an if condition would need to be added to the first loop **to avoid Key collision**. I would also recommend you to use the [MailAddress Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=net-6.0) to parse your emails.

```
$map = @{}

foreach($line in $csv1) {
    $mail = [mailaddress]$line.PrimarySmtpAddress
    $map[$mail.User] = $mail
}

$csv2 | Select-Object *, @{
    Name = 'SecondaryDomain'
    Expression = { $map[([mailaddress]$_.PrimarySmtpAddress).User].Host }
}, @{
    Name = 'SecondarySmtpAddress'
    Expression = { $map[([mailaddress]$_.PrimarySmtpAddress).User].Address }
}

$result | Format-Table
```